# Not able to get screen's outerHeight on mobile devices but it works for desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery to get the Screen's Height using this :

JQuery:

```
$(window).outerHeight();
```

When i debug it ,it shows the right screen height for larger screens, but it is not showing the right height for the mobile devices .

What could be the problem ?
I am using the OuterHeight on a website to fix the NAVBAR after scrolling a distance equal to screen's Height . But for some reason it doesn't work fine for mobile devices. 
This is the link to the page :  [Link](https://64094d4bb435230d27e37e949d79ba9c5a99016c.googledrive.com/host/0B4pizyWNEvkdYng4R084ZkdrbHM)

Why doesn't it read the mobile device's height ?

Comment: why not using window.outerHeight?

Comment: yeah that doesn't make any difference i guess, am just using jquery and what u mentioned is plain javascript.